# Eclipse installer error, looks like it is trying to use Java 1.8

Tags: java, eclipse

I just followed the Eclipse websites links to download the latest version, and after running from the terminal

```
$ ./eclipse-inst
```

It goes through the installation process but returns

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-Duser.dir=/root/eclipse/java-photon/eclipse
-jar /root/eclipse/java-photon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /root/eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /root/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.700.v20180518-1200/eclipse_1705.so
-startup /root/eclipse/java-photon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata eb0026
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-Duser.dir=/root/eclipse/java-photon/eclipse
-jar /root/eclipse/java-photon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar
```

It looks like it requires version 1.8 but I believe my repository, the one recommended elsewhere which is `webupd8team/java`, has provided version 1.9.  I doubt the best thing to do is use 1.8, but I'm really not sure what is the best way to resolve this.  I wasn't able to search the error but it may be because the error is so massive that I don't know which parts of it to search for.

I thought about trying to edit the `eclipse.ini` file since I had done that to overcome another error but I don't see anything in it that looks like it would require 1.9:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.dist
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
#--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
#256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
```

Comment: This looks like Eclipse Photon which requires **at least** Java 8. It works fine with Java 9 and 10 so that is not the problem.

Comment: You might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609160/eclipse-returns-error-message-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-1) Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the link but unfortunately I added what I believe is the right line to the `eclipse.ini` file and it didn't change the behavior.